# Isolated scope binding doesn't work when updated inside a $scope.$watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Why does the below code not work? I'm trying to get pass `x` to the directive, then updated the value of `x` based on `y`which is internal to the directive.

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.x=[];
}]);

app.controller('dirCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.y=[];
  
  $scope.click=function(){
    $scope.y.push({});
  }
  
  $scope.$watch('y', function(){
    $scope.x=$scope.y;
    console.log("$scope.x updated in $watch call");
  },true);
}]);
                           
app.directive('directive', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            x: '=',
        },
        template: '<div ng-controller="dirCtrl"><button ng-click="click()">clicky</button>y:{{y}}</div>'
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <directive x='x'></directive>
    x:{{x}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$scope.$watch()` doesn't do a deep watch. The `y` reference per se never change, just its contents. Use  `$scope.$watchCollection()` instead.

**UPDATE:**

When you use a binding without a dot notation, it ends up creating a new slot inside the $scope. The trick is to use something like `obj.x`.

See the changes needed:

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.obj = {
    x: []
  };
}]);

app.controller('dirCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.y=[];
  
  $scope.click=function(){
    $scope.y.push({});
  };

  $scope.$watch('y', function(){
    $scope.obj.x = $scope.y;
    console.log("$scope.obj.x updated in $watch call");
  },true);
}]);

app.directive('directive', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            obj: '=',
        },
        template: '<div ng-controller="dirCtrl"><button ng-click="click()">clicky</button>y:{{y}}</div>'
    };
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <directive obj='obj'></directive>
    x: {{obj.x}}
  </div>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: `$scope.$watch` is triggered properly. Check your logs when you press the button.

Comment: You're right, my bad. I'll edit my answer. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Also a good read about the "dot problem" http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/19/5-angularjs-antipatterns-and-pitfalls/ and the linked pages

Comment: So there is no way to just bind this to an array? Why?

Comment: No. You have to pass an object or share data through a service that both directive and controller would go for its data. But I believe the "dotted" approach is more simple to reuse.

Answer (score 0):

You're sending in a Number which is not an object and therefor not bound by reference.
Put it as a property of an object instead and pass that into the directive:

```
$scope.obj = {
    x: 5
};
```

Comment: Is my real usecase its an array of objects, not a number. Ill try to update my question.